# Win 2K8 R2 Server, 2 NICs - internal and external - network configuration

Tags: windows, nic

I have a Windows server with 2 NICs, a modem/router, a switch and some client computers. I have been trying to set everything up like so:

Internet - external NIC - server - internal NIC - switch - client computers

I have tried the following configuration:

Server
DHCP enabled
DNS enabled

```
Ext NIC
IP: 192.168.0.1
SM: 255.255.255.0
GW: 192.168.0.254 - modem/router from ISP
DNS: 8.8.8.8

Int. NIC
IP: 192.168.1.1
SM: 255.255.255.0
GW: blank
DNS: 8.8.8.8
```

However, none of the client machines can connect to the internet.

Everything I tried seems to fail, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why would you not just plug all of the clients and the server into the switch?

Comment: Well I did think of that but I eventually want to setup squid proxy and possible dansguardian to protect the kids.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup the server to be a router using RRAS http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458974.aspx -- but really that's pretty silly in your situation.

You should simply do as Joe points out.  Server and clients into the switch, switch into the modem/router.  Server handles DHCP and DNS still.  Modem/router has DHCP server disabled.  Modem/Router's LAN IP is a static IP in the same network that the Server is in and that the clients are in (unless you want to mess with VLANs/routing).